# How to remove lines from lines in C#?

Tags: c#, string, newline, lines

Trying to create code that removes a block of lines from a set of lines. I've stared at this code for 50 minutes, don't know why it doesn't work (Doesn't seem to remove anything). Please help?

```
        public string[] removeLinesFromLines(string[] remLns, string[] lns)
        {
            //convert lns into equivalent string
            string lnst = "";
            foreach (string ln in lns)
            {
                lnst += ln + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            lnst = lnst.Trim(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());

            //convert remlns into equivalent string
            string remt = "";
            foreach (string ln in remLns)
            {
                remt += ln + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            remt = remt.Trim(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());

            //delete all instances of remlns from lns
            lnst = lnst.Replace(remt, "");

            //convert back into array
            return Regex.Split(lnst, Environment.NewLine); 
}
```

With lns =

a

b

c

d

b

d

c

and remlns =

b

c

The output should be...

a

d

b

d

c

The code is really simple! It's like 4 different lines, functionally speaking.

Comment: That's because it only replaces it if it matches the whole `remt` string. Which isn't going to happen I think.

Comment: It's normal that you stare for 50 minutes on it : it's really convoluted. You should try to look for simpler solutions such as @un-lucky's :)

Comment: Nah, it's really quite simple bro. I've commented it to make it a bit easier to understand.

Comment: Found the issue: My code works, the input didn't, lol.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
public string[] removeLinesFromLines(string[] remLns, string[] lns)
        {
            var result = lns.Except(remLns);
            return result.ToArray(); 
        }
```

This will return an array of strings, that are Present in `lns` but not in `remLns`

Comment: Seems to have taken out every single line that contained any one of the lines in remLns (With remln being 11 lines long, it took out 150 lines from lns.). Trying to remove the whole block of text in RemLns from lns, not each individual line in remln that's present in lns. Looks elegant, however. From the example above, your answer produces "A D D" because it removes every instance of B and C.